# Inequality with probability on Hypergeometric

Tags: probability, inequality

There are 30 computers in a classroom, 4 of which are very slow, 20 students come to the class and are seated randomly each in front of a computer. Show that $$9P(-3<X<3)\ge 1 $$. I got that $E(X)=\frac{8}{3}$ and $V(X)=\frac{2\cdot4\cdot26}{3 \cdot 29}$. I tried to solve the inequality using Chebyshev's inequality and I have: $$P(-\epsilon+\frac{8}{3}<X<\epsilon+\frac{8}{3})\ge1-\frac{2\cdot4\cdot26}{29\epsilon^2} $$

And it doesn't work because if I set $\epsilon=\frac{1}{3}$ , I get $3$ on the right, but $\frac{7}{3}$ on the left instead of $3$. Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: Where's the definition of $X$?

Comment: It's defined in the first sentence

Comment: Hypergeometric distribution